# Do coroutines from PEP-492 bypass the GIL in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, coroutine, gil

Python 3.5 includes co-routine support with [PEP-492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/); which is great and all.... assuming the coroutines go around the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock); does anyone know if that's the case? Or, should I just keep using the `multiprocessing` module?

Comment: Why would they need to go around the GIL? (They don't).

Comment: Because the GIL is only needed when accessing the interpreter loop from concurrent threads. Coroutines are not threads; they cooperate within the same thread. Thus the GIL doesn't come into play.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that coroutines do not bypass the GIL.

The reason is, that coroutines are never processed in parallel. Coroutines are a language feature that does some kind of pseudo-parallel processing without real parallel task, thread or anything else execution. Only one coroutine is ever executed at once.

Remember: Even, when using coroutines, you can still have different threads in your program!

So, the GIL is not affected, because the GIL is only a means to prevent *real* parallel processing of threads in specific parts of the Python interpreter, that could end in corruption of global data.

When you are using a thread-enabled version of Python, you will have the GIL -- and no thread and also no coroutines "bypass" the GIL. But the coroutines are not affected by the GIL, as threads are, since threads could be stopped by the GIL, when entering critical sections. Coroutines are not, unless a second thread is running ... (but that is the problem of the threading in your program, not of the coroutines).

Of course, you can (at least it was possible some time ago) create a Python interpreter version with no thread-support (when you really don't need it), by compiling the interpreter yourself. In such a version, the GIL should be not executed.

But you must be sure, that no module you are using, is using threading, since that module would break.

Edit:
After reading your question a second time, I guess, what you really want to ask is, if the GIL-overhead (applicable in threads) is lower in coroutines.

I would say, yes. Even when the GIL is active in your version of the interpreter. Because by limiting your execution to cooperative multiprocessing, the GIL will not (or less, when you still have more than one thread) affect your coroutines, as it is when you have multiple worker threads. There will be less (or no) contention on reserving the GIL.

There is also the webserver "Tornado" that uses coprocessing technologies for a longer time now in Python, very successfully. That should show, that coprocessing is definitively a good choice, when using Python. Also there are other examples of programs that are fast by using coprocessing technology (e.g. Nginx).

Comment: 3.2+ already has much less GIL-contention-overhead than 2.x, partly because it prevents the thread releasing the GIL from immediately reacquiring it in the presence of other threads, and partly because it counts milliseconds instead of opcodes.  But yes, having to deal with the GIL, perform CPU context switches, etc. is expensive, and coroutines are much cheaper.